# error while joining tables using nesting in SQL

Tags: mysql

My query looks like this

```
SELECT level1_idnt, day_dt, avg(sls_price) as avg_rp
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT level1_idnt,day_dt,sls_price 
                     FROM (SELECT a.level1_idnt,a.day_dt,a.sls_price,b.op
                           FROM (SELECT level1_idnt,day_dt,sls_price 
                           FROM md1.loc_sku_dy_act_pos_full_v2 
                           WHERE seasn_cd =2 and day_dt >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and day_dt <= '2015-09-30 00:00:00'
                                )l0 
                           a left join (SELECT level1_idnt, AVG(org_sales_price) as op
                                        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT level1_idnt, org_sales_price
                                        FROM md1.item_lv1_org_price_m
                                        WHERE fr_cntry_cde = '01' AND org_sales_price IS NOT NULL
                                        ) l
                                        GROUP BY level1_idnt)l_op
                           b 
                           ON a.level1_idnt = b.level1_idnt
                           )l1
            WHERE sls_price <= op
      )l2
      WHERE sls_price is not null
     ) l3
GROUP BY level1_idnt,day_dt;
```

for this I am getting an error

```
syntax error at or near "a"
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this;) it looks like a `alias` mistake in subquery.

```
SELECT level1_idnt, day_dt, avg(sls_price) as avg_rp
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT level1_idnt,day_dt,sls_price
                     FROM (SELECT a.level1_idnt,a.day_dt,a.sls_price,b.op
                           FROM (SELECT level1_idnt,day_dt,sls_price
                                 FROM md1.loc_sku_dy_act_pos_full_v2
                                 WHERE seasn_cd =2 and day_dt >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and day_dt <= '2015-09-30 00:00:00'
                                )
                          a left join (SELECT level1_idnt, AVG(org_sales_price) as op
                                       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT level1_idnt, org_sales_price
                                             FROM md1.item_lv1_org_price_m
                                             WHERE fr_cntry_cde = '01' AND org_sales_price IS NOT NULL
                                            ) l
                                       GROUP BY level1_idnt)
                    b
ON a.level1_idnt = b.level1_idnt
)l1
WHERE sls_price <= op
)l2
WHERE sls_price is not null
) l3
GROUP BY level1_idnt,day_dt;
```

Before `a` there is a string ***l0*** and before `b` a string ***l_op***

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to give two names to the same subquery:

```
(SELECT level1_idnt,day_dt,sls_price 
 FROM md1.loc_sku_dy_act_pos_full_v2 
 WHERE seasn_cd =2 and day_dt >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00' 
 and day_dt <= '2015-09-30 00:00:00')l0 a
```

or call the subquery "l0" or "a"

and the same situation with "b":

```
(SELECT level1_idnt, AVG(org_sales_price) as op
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT level1_idnt, org_sales_price
       FROM md1.item_lv1_org_price_m
       WHERE fr_cntry_cde = '01' AND org_sales_price IS NOT NULL) l
 GROUP BY level1_idnt) l_op b
```

or you call the subquery "l_op" or "b"

From what I can see I think you can replace "a" with "l0" and "b" with "l_op" in this line

```
SELECT a.level1_idnt,a.day_dt,a.sls_price,b.op
```

and remove the names "a" and "b" from the subquery